# MongoDB Duplicate Value Error even though I don't want it to be unique

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, duplicates

`MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: MyNotebookDB.notes index: title_1 dup key: { title: "Data Structures" }` 
This is title in my model.

```
title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
```

When I first created my model, then I did set title: {unique: true}, but later I didn't need the title to be unique, so I removed it.
I dont even have validations on this models/inputs.
But it still doesn't accept Duplicate Values and shows this error.

Comment: it seems _id is not getting generated by default, and there is no other key in your schema hence title is treated like the primary key.

Comment: @r7r but when title is different, the _id is generated. So, why not when title is same.

Comment: then try to drop collections and start again, or delete the index manually.

check db.{COLLECTION_NAME}.getIndexes(), if you find one on title delete
db.{COLLECTION_NAME}.dropIndex()

Answer (score 3):

i think you need manually delete index which require title to be unique

Comment: i know, but error means you still have index on your db. Go to mongo shell or mongodb compass and delete it

Comment: Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 2):

Error E11000 is generated by the mongod process when an insert would result in a duplicate entry in an index marked as unique.

Check the indexes on the collection via the mongo shell, you will likely find one there that you don't expect.

Answer (score -2):

I have this problem too like you , and i figure out every field except title can be non unique but just title act like this so i changed title to another thing like game so problem solved

Comment: Please add relevant sources to justify your answer. This will help the asker and also new folks to understand the relevant issue.